# Accessing input data and passing it to a Nunjucks macro

Tags: arrays, input, macros, key, nunjucks

I'm messing around with the govuk prototype kit.

Here's my component asking for a date of birth split into three input types.

```
{{ govukDateInput({
          id: "date-of-birth",
          namePrefix: "date-of-birth",
          fieldset: {
            legend: {
              text: "What is your date of birth?",
              isPageHeading: true,
              classes: "govuk-fieldset__legend--xl"
            }
          },
          hint: {
            html: "We use this to calculate if you're over the State Pension age or not.<br>For example, 31 3 1980"
          },
          items: [
            {
              name: "day",
              classes: "govuk-input--width-2",
              autocomplete: "day"
            },
            {
              name: "month",
              classes: "govuk-input--width-2",
              autocomplete: "month"
            },
            {
              name: "year",
              classes: "govuk-input--width-4",
              autocomplete: "year"
            }
          ]
        }) }}
```

I can display the full date like so:

```
<p>{{ data['date-of-birth-day'] }} {{ data['date-of-birth-month'] }} {{ data['date-of-birth-year'] }}</p>
```

However, I'm wanting to pass the data into another component (macro).
It works with just one key e.g. day, but how can I add the other two / string together multiple within one.

e.g.

```
{
          key: {
            text: "Data of birth"            
          },
          value: {
            text: data['date-of-birth-day']
          },
          actions: {
            items: [
              {
                href: "#",
                text: "Change",
                visuallyHiddenText: "birthday"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

Thanks